# Why does arm-linux-androideabi-gcc enforce -fpic?

Tags: android, gcc, cross-compiling

I was surprised to see that gcc enforces code to be position independent, even if such flag wasn't provided explicitly in the command line.

I suspect it might have to do with certain expectations from Android's dynamic loader (e.g. expectations on relocation types and freedom to put code wherever it wants) but I am not certain.

Can anybody explain why that really is?

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --version | grep GCC
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc (GCC) 4.4.3

$ arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -v -S main.c |& grep fpic
 /home1/local64/android-toolchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/cc1 -quiet -v -iprefix /home1/local64/android-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/ -isysroot /home1/local64/android-toolchain/bin/../sysroot main.c -mbionic -fpic -quiet -dumpbase main.c -march=armv5te -mfloat-abi=soft -mfpu=vfp -auxbase main -version -o main.s
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with Android 4.1, Google is forcing full [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) to overcome common security exploits, see [this article](https://blog.duosecurity.com/2012/07/exploit-mitigations-in-android-jelly-bean-4-1/) for more details.

Position Independent Code (PIC) is required for this to work but also PIE (Position Independent Executable) too.