# Is -fPIC always on a bad idea?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Is there any harm in always compiling with `-fPIC` even if I might not intend to link the resulting relocatable object files into a shared library?

Comment: Relocation costs extra indirection and increases code size, and you may wish to take that into account. But best to measure and compare!

Comment: Related: [Why does arm-linux-androideabi-gcc enforce -fpic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990461/why-does-arm-linux-androideabi-gcc-enforce-fpic)

Answer (score 2):

Well, always compiling with -fPIC will produce a bit more bloated and a bit slower code.

Difference would be less visible on x64 target, I believe

You shall measure and decide if those differences are relevant for you app, you might be ok with it

Comment: It worth mention that there are not only x86 and x86_64 out there (their current share maybe even less than everything else)